Everit JSON schema validation - Process "good" records in payload
I have a JSON payload of below format which a REST service will receive in POST request -
{
 "packages" : [
    {
    "packageid" : "12233",.....
    "events" : [
        {
        "eventid" : "33444",.........
        },
        ...... <<one or more events>>
     },
     .......<<one or more packages>>        
    ]
 ]
}

I am planning to apply everit schema validation on incoming JSON payload. Requirement is that response should contain all schema validation errors but service should also process the "good" packages and/or events.
First part is doable. For second part, based on the schema validation errors reported, is there any easy way to identify the "good" packages and/or events which can then be further processed?
Regards
Jacob
